# Open Graph API sort order, or simple jQuery/JavaScript sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, sorting

I'm getting a list of friends scores by calling the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<appid>/scores?access_token=' + userToken;
```

It works great, but I would like to sort by highest score (result.score). There are lots of options for paging like "limit, offset, until" that you can specify inline in the URL, but I don't see anything in the documentation for sorting.

If that's not possible, what is the **simplest** way in jQuery or JavaScript to sort the following statement:

```
 success: function (data) {
     $("#highScores").html("");
     $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
         $("#highScores").append("<div class='score'><span class='scoreName'>" + item.user.name + "</span><span class='scoreValue'>" + item.score + "</span>");
     });
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of one hack that I'll use if someone doesn't have a simpler solution.

save the last score, if new score is higher do prepend instead of append.

```
    success: function (data) {
        $("#highScores").html("");
        var lastScore = 0;
        $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
            if (lastScore < item.score) {
                $("#highScores").prepend("<div class='score'><span class='scoreName'>" + item.user.name + "</span><span class='scoreValue'>" + item.score + "</span>");
            } else {
                $("#highScores").append("<div class='score'><span class='scoreName'>" + item.user.name + "</span><span class='scoreValue'>" + item.score + "</span>");
            }
            lastScore = item.score;
        });
    },
```